# Maximum Probability to hit the bear.

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

A bear hides itself either behind a bush $a$ with the probability $\frac{9}{25}$ or behind bush $b$ with probability $\frac{16}{25}$ . A hunter has $5$ bullets each of which can be fired either at bush $a$ or $b$ . Hunter hits each target independently with an accuracy of $\frac{1}{4}$ . How many bullets can be fired at the bush to hit the bear with maximum probability (assume that the bullet hitting the bush also hit the bear)?

How to incorporate the term maximum probability in the solution?

Comment: Hint: Suppose the hunter fires all five bullets at bush $a$.  What is the probability he hits the bear?

Comment: I guess the statement should be "How many bullets should be fired at _each_ bush to hit the bear... " ?

Comment: Compute. There are only $6$ possibilities to worry about if one does no preliminary thinking. And it is clear that $3$ at Bush $b$ is better than $3$ at Bush $a$, and similarly for $4$ or $5$.

Answer (score 3):

The hunter should pursue sequential strategy and not decide on distribution of shots in advance. Initial odds of the bear being behind bush $b$ are $r_0=\frac {16}9$ and it's clear that the first shot shout be at $b$. If he misses, odds get multiplied by $\frac 3 4$ to yield $r_1=r_0\cdot \frac 3 4=\frac 4 3$ so on the second shot he should shoot at $b$ as well. If he misses again, $r_2=1$ and then he is indifferent, so, for simplicity, he chooses to shoot at $b$ again. If he misses, he'll shoot at $a$ and if he misses then, he'll be indifferent.

Hence optimal strategies are of the form $bbbax$ and $bbabx$ where $x\in\{a,b\}$.

---

If the hunter *doesn't* know the outcome of his shooting (the bear is hiding and not roaring as I initially assumed), then we need to minimize $$\frac 9{25}(\frac 3 4)^i+\frac {16}{25}(\frac 3 4)^{5-i}$$ for $i$- number of shots fired at bush $a$. Minimum is achieved for $i=1,2$ leading to a similar set of strategies but without minimization of the shots fired.

Comment: It's not clear from the problem statement if the hunter knows when the bullets hits the bear.

Comment: The hunter will know since the bear will stop roaring ;). It is indeed unclear, but the choice of initial probabilities points to the fact that it's the interpretation meant by the asker. I updated to include alternative interpretation. I think both methods yeild same probabilities of hitting the bear but the first one minimizes the number of shots fired.

Comment: Wow really fast answer. +1. Although a bit strange that the bear is hiding and roaring at the same time ;)

Comment: Well, if hiding and silent, it will roar when hit :)

Comment: @eman The sequential strategy is needed if the hunter doesn't know exactly how many bullets he has/which bullets are live. He basically needs to behave as if the receives negative feedback from all of his shots because if he ever hits a bear, his future actions are irrelevant.

Comment: I assumed he would know if he hit a bear in that a dead bear would fall out of the bush.  It never occurred to me he wouldn't know if he hit the bear.  Which leads to questions.  If he doesn't know if he hit the bear how is he going to find out.  I doubt he's going to just walk up to a bush and peak if there's a possibility of a live and very angry bear behind it.  Also how does he know a bear is hiding at all.